# GMock - how to refresh mock return values?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I've got a test that is something like this:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using namespace ::testing;

class IMyInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~IMyInterface() = default;
    virtual void* DoAllocate(size_t size) = 0;
};

class MockMyInterface : public IMyInterface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(DoAllocate, void*(size_t));
};

class InterfaceUser
{
public:
    void DoIt(IMyInterface& iface)
    {
        void* ptr = iface.DoAllocate(1024);
        free(ptr);
        ptr = iface.DoAllocate(1024);
        free(ptr);
    }
};

TEST(MyTest, AllocateMock)
{
    MockMyInterface mockIFace;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockIFace, DoAllocate(1024)).WillRepeatedly(Return(malloc(1024)));

    InterfaceUser user;
    user.DoIt(mockIFace);
}

int main(int numArgs, char** args)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&numArgs, args);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This will crash because the "real" code that is being tested calls `DoAllocate` with `1024` twice. But gmock seems to only do:

```
Return(malloc(1024))
```

Once even though its called twice. Obviously this is a problem because it means malloc is called once with 1024 and then the "real" code is freeing the same pointer twice.

How do I force gmock to actually execute the `malloc(1024)` on each mock call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup you expectations by pre-allocating buffers, like this:

```
void *buffer1 = malloc(1024);
void *buffer2 = malloc(1024);

EXPECT_CALL(mockIFace, DoAllocate(1024)).Times(2)
    .WillOnce(Return(buffer1))
    .WillOnce(Return(buffer2));
```

Comment: Thanks - turns you the malloc call can be inline within the Return() this way too :)

Comment: @paulm You are welcome! I've written the answer in haste, and since I was not 100% sure if inline within `Return` will work, I've used temporaries instead. :)